# StackOverFlow error - from instantiating my object class

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am trying to make a class in Java that builds an object of type `Action` which holds three ints and returns it to my other class in the array `history`, where `history` is an
array of type `Action`. When it is called I immediately get an endless loop; hence the stack overflow.

**Error - I printed 1 line, it goes on...**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sudokugame.Action.<init>(Action.java:7)
```

**Class:**

```
public class Action {

    Action a;
    public Action(int i, int o, int p){
      a = new Action(i,o,p);
    }

    public void   setAction(int n, int b, int c){

    }

    public Action  getAction(){
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Your constructor calls itself recursively forever. A sure way to overflow a stack :)

```
public Action(int i, int o, int p){
    //why do you do this?
    a = new Action(i,o,p);
}
```

Maybe what you really wanted to do was just store i,o and p in the class instance?

```
public class Action {

  int i;
  int o;
  int p;

  public Action(int i, int o, int p){
    this.i = i;
    this.o = o;
    this.p = p;
  }

  ...
}
```

(edit: see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1063595/stackoverflow-error-from-instantiating-my-object-class/1063632#1063632) for fuller example)

Answer (score 3):

Try doing it this way:

```
public class Action {

  int i;
  int o;
  int p;

  public Action(int i, int o, int p){
    this.i = i;
    this.o = o;
    this.p = p;
  }

  public void setAction(int n, int b, int c){
    this.i = i;
    this.o = o;
    this.p = p;
  }

  public Action getAction(){
    return this;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
a = new Action(i,o,p);
```

You are invoking the constructor again for a new instance inside the constructor of the class itself.  Since each subsequent call to the constructor will create a new constructor call there is no way for the stack to unwind, therefore creating a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your instantiating the class within itself.

Comment: Why would this be a problem? The recursion is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Action class really need to hold on to a reference to another Action?

```
Action a;
```

Specifically, is this line necessary? What are you using it for?

Answer (score 0):

sure your constructor has recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

The [Command design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) is one way to approach a situation where you want to have a history of actions taken so they can be undone, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor have recursive call.